# PHP - Capture part of URL and detect URL change

Tags: php

I am trying to achieve the above stated. Is there a way I can do the following

URL: 
https://www.example.com/p/8488771-97811-test-test-test-test-test-test-test.html#/1234-567-uk_89_eu_00

How can I capture "97811" only?

As the site is also changing the link dynamically because there is a dropdown feature when user choose an item or another item, "97811" will change to automatically -

Example: 
https://www.example.com/p/8488771-97812-test-test-test-test-test-test-test.html#/1234-567-uk_89_eu_00

https://www.example.com/p/8488771-97813-test-test-test-test-test-test-test.html#/1234-567-uk_89_eu_00

Thus, I need to capture and detect if there is a change in url.

I have tried with the following codes -

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

It is returning the full URL but I need to get only the stated number.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what your question is. How do you want to fetch the numbers/part of the string? If you already get the full URL with your code, have you tried with a regex or splitting the string? What do you want help with?

Comment: Yes, precisely. I need help with retrieving only the number as I would like to put it as a variable to process.

Comment: Yes, I understood that, but how is it relevant that the URL can change dynamically?

Comment: Ah I see, because there is a feature in the website that has a dropdown for products. when a user choose another item, it will change the link.

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly what you're asking, please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and consider [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53177807/edit) your question to show example output based on code you've written, and what you want.

Comment: I have edited my post. Is it better?

Comment: Not really, it still doesn't follow a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)-pattern. Did you read the link? You can't really detect an URL-change through PHP if the page changes URL dynamically without a server refresh for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php explode function. First you can explode request_uri with delimiter '/'. It will return an array. Then you should explode again your element of the array with delimiter '-'. Hope this will help you.

You can get more about explode function here-
http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php

Comment: Thank you. That has directed me well. I used something like this....        $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $exploded_1 = explode("/", $url);
        $exploded_2 = explode("-", $exploded_1[5]);
        $model = $exploded_2[1];

Comment: May I know if I can detect if the link has change? and capture the number again.....

Comment: You can keep the value in a session variable. Then check it with the current value, if it changes then update the session variable with it.

Comment: Yes but how do I detect if there is a change in the URL then? I am unsure of this.

Comment: If it changes only locally , you can't @Enthu. You must detect it with javascript on client side

Comment: That is something I am stuck with. I am unable to detect when URL changes without refresh or reload unfortunately. and I am unfamiliar with history.pushState, as I have read